# WSO2 ESB and Basic Auth: still don't get it

Tags: authentication, wso2-esb

This can't be as hard as it looks. I'm learning WSO2 ESB 4.8.1. I want to create REST service proxies with plain XML, no SOAP. I want to authenticate the request using the HTTP Basic Auth credentials (NOT WS-ADDRESSING), against a user I've created in the default WSO2 ESB user store via the admin UI.

Example in the docs I see requires 1) creating or downloading a custom handler and 2) authenticates against hard coded values, which is ridiculous. If this is a serious ESB contender I would expect Basic Auth to be easy and running right out of the box.

Reference:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Securing+APIs#SecuringAPIs-BasicAuthUsingaBasicAuthhandler